# Sync users from a security group?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, user-profile-service

How do I sync users profiles from a specific security group?

Comment: I dont think so you can sync a specific security group, if i understand correctly. Because UPA target only OU level.

Comment: also in 2013 there is Active Directory Import option avaiable, you can try to write LDAP syntax to filter while setting the connection. to get the idea for LDAP query check this http://mindsharpblogs.com/wayne/archive/2005/06/15/497.html

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Thanks your suggestion help, I looked into AD Import and wrote the LDAP query the article suggested. If you write up your answer I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think So you can Sync a Specific security group instead of all.Because UPA target only OU level.

I think, your best option is use the Active Directory Import option(new in SharePoint 2013) and write yours own LDAP query filter to get it done. Looks like a complex query.

Answer (score 0):

On AD Connection -->  synchronization connection --> Container  , just select group u want to synch.
PS : http://smallcitydesign.com/user-profile-synchronization-importing-users-and-security-groups-in-sharepoint-2010/